# repeating Manager alarms every week

Tags: android

I want to do a specific task each week .
So I used an Alarm Manager
when user click button alarmManager running
blow code Works properly:

```
       public void set_alarm(int reapte)
{
    Context context=getBaseContext();
    Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
//  calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20); // For 1 PM or 2 PM
    //calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 41);
    Intent intent= new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    intent.putExtra("size", reapte);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,
              intent ,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7, pi);


    }
```

The problem that I have.
  When the user clicks. Alarm Manager runs the same moment.
And next week will run.
I want to first run the alarm from next week
.sorry My language is not good

Answer (score 0):

Try this
you can set the day from which alarm will begin.

`calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);`
where sunday=1 and so on to sat=7

and set the time 2 min before from current time when alarm was set,so it will same day of next week

Comment: thanks but  I get minute .... calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);  and set alendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute-2);. but dont work

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the answer

WEEK_OF_MONTH values  is between 1 and 4.

so
I use below code:

```
    int week=calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH);
    int day=calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    int hour=calendar.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
    int minute= calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, day);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour); 
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,minute);

    int next_week=week+1;

    if(next_week>4)
         next_week=1;
    calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, next_week); 

   //other code
```